# revkit installation

Tags: apt, application-development, python, compiling

so i need to install this software called revkit on ubuntu 12.10. below are the instructions as per the manual:

1. Requirements
   RevKit needs a couple of packages which can easily be installed with the distribution’s
   package manager. Below the commands for common distributions are listed. In distri-
   butions not listed it can be done analogue but the package names might deviate.
   Ubuntu, Mint Linux (for the Python Interface Ubuntu 9.10 or higher is required):

> sudo apt−get install build−essential cmake python−dev ipython
>   python−qt4 python−numpy
>   
>   openSUSE:
>
> sudo zypper install gcc−c++ cmake python−devel IPython
>   python−qt4 python−numpy

Fedora:

> sudo yum install wget gcc−c++ cmake python−devel ipython PyQt4 numpy

1
2
For a description of how to extend RevKit with own approaches or how to integrate RevKit in own
C++-projects, respectively, we refer the reader to the developers’ documentation. The developers’
documentation (including an API) is provided by means of doxygen in the sources of RevKit as well
as on http://www.revkit.org.RevKit – User Manual
For Fedora users: In order to run RevKit, SE Linux needs to be disabled. This can be
done temporarily or permanently as follows:
Temporarily:

> sudo /usr/sbin/setenforce 0

Permanently: Change ”enforcing” to ”disabled” in ”/etc/selinux/config” and reboot.
3. Download and Installation
RevKit can be downloaded from the www.revkit.org website. Opening a Bash shell and
assuming that the file revkit-1.3.tar.gz is in the current working directory, first the pack-
age needs to be unpacked:

> tar xvfz revkit−1.3.tar . gz
>
> cd revkit−1.3

Then, you can build the toolkit. The build process is divided into two scripts. First,
the RevKit environment is created using the bootstrap script. Afterwards, the RevKit
algorithms are built using the build script. This has the benefit of running the second
script only if changes have been made on the algorithms but not on the environment.
The bootstrap script should only be called once at the beginning.
More precisely, first run the bootstrap script:

> ./make.py bootstrap

This will download and compile all dependencies automatically. For that purpose,
compiling boost takes some time. If you already have installed boost using the distri-
bution’s package manager, the option -DBOOST PATH can be used to specify its path,
e.g. -DBOOST PATH=/usr. Alternatively you can specify the boost include and libs
path separately by using –boost, –boost-include-dir and –boost-lib-dir as arguments.
Plaese make sure that your version of boost satisfies the requirements.
After bootstraping the environment, the build script needs to be executed. To run
this script manually call:

> ./make.py build

This will build the whole RevKit suite including the core, algorithms, examples, and
the Python bindings. The Python bindings enable the CLI to use RevKit like a shell.
If the system cannot build the Python bindings or if they are not needed, they can be
deactivated by calling

> ./make.py build −DBUILD BINDINGS=OFF

3
Further packages which are not available in the distrubition’s package manager (as
e.g. CUDD or PUMA) are downloaded and installed automatically from the bootstrap
script. Boost is also required and will be downloaded and installed by default.RevKit – User Manual
instead.
The build script must be called at least once. Afterwards, the sources only need to be
compiled again if local changes have been performed. Alternatively, the program make
can be executed manually by calling

> make

in the build directory.
The build script also provides the options of enabling and disabling the compilation
of unstable and example algorithms by using the parameters -DBUILD UNSTABLE
and -DBUILD EXAMPLES.

4.RevKit – User Manual
After the installation, RevKit is fully functional and ready to use. In this section, we
describe how to apply the most important functions using “out of the box”-tools. This
should provide a starting point to become familiar with the framework and its func-
tionalities.
4.1. RevKit Graphical User Interface
The RevKit Graphical User Interface enables the creation and execution of customized
design processes to be executed. Therefore, a GUI is utilized where the respective tasks
can easily be put together by means of item blocks connected to a graph. Each item
performs an operation and may have ports for the respective input parameters and
output results. Input ports can be connected to output ports forming a channel when
they support the same data types.
In order to start the RevKit Graphical User Interface, the following command has to
be invoked from within the root directory of RevKit:

> ./tools/gui/gui.py

The use of the GUI is illustrated by means of several tutorial-videos at the www.revkit.org
website.

i tried to do it many times but wasn't successful. here's a copy my last attempt.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7466799/
 can someone please tell me the errors that are occuring and how to rectify them. i need to get the gui interface of revkit somehow. if not can u describe the process in detail. i'll be really really grateful.

Comment: yaa actually it is but i just wanted to give all the instructions required for installation so that you know the person answering has full information regarding what i'm trying to do and since that wasn't in my previous question i thought it'd be better to post a new one

Comment: You can edit your previous question to give additional instructions. Needless to create a second one